# Ultimo CMS Home Page - I would like to know about displaying new products with sliders

Tags: magento2.2.4, ultimo

I want to output Ultimo's extended function (New in Store) on CMS page with Magento 2.2.4.

However, the Ultimo Theme document does not show how to do it.

If you know how to respond, would you please teach me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ultimo code to show products from specific category.Place below code into CMS page with category-id.

```
{{block class="Infortis\Base\Block\Product\ProductList\Featured"
template="product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="3" product_count="12" hide_button="1" block_name="My Products"}}
```

Comment: I understand how to call a product grid with a category ID. What I want to know is to output a new product to the CMS page using "docroot / app / design / frontend / Infortis / base / Infortis_Base / templates / product / list / slider.phtml".

Thank you for your review.

Comment: please accept my anwser